# replace the presence of certain characters in a string in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string named `pageList=  [[],[2567,2568,],[2569,2570,2571,2537,],[2538,2586,2587,2588,],[2589,2590,2591,2592,2593,]]`
I need to remove the presnce of `[],` with  (empty) and `,[]` with  (empty) and `,]` with `]` . I tried the code

```
              pageList = pageList.replace(/,]/g,']');                 
              pageList = pageList.replace(/[]/g,''); 
              pageList = pageList.replace(/[/]/g,'');
```

But its is replacing the `,]` with `]` but removing the `,[]` and `[],` is not working.The output I am getting now is `[[],[2567,2568],[2569,2570,2571,2537],[2538,2586,2587,2588],[2589,2590,2591,2592,2593]]`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need regex here as it is not a string.

This being an array so extra `,` will automatically be removed. To remove `[]` you can use `.filter()` here

```js
var pageList=  [[],[2567,2568,],[2569,2570,2571,2537,],[2538,2586,2587,2588,],[2589,2590,2591,2592,2593,]];

pageList = pageList.filter(el => el.length!==0)

console.log(pageList);
```

PS: If your data is in string format then you might need to parse it to array by doing `JSON.parse(pageList);`

Comment: In this code if the string is only `[]` it will not remove anything